# AM-GM Inequality concept challenged!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ are positive numbers and $abc=9$, then find the minimum value of $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=?$

Someone's approach is [image: this]

but for this to be possible, $a=b=c=1$. which doesn't satisfies $abc=9$.
Where does the above method go wrong and what should be the correct answer?

Comment: If $a=b=c=1$, then $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=8\neq 24$.

Comment: @Rakeysh Vishwakarma There are no positive numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $abc=9$ and  $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=24$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by AM-GM,
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=1+(a+b+c)+(bc+ac+ab)+abc\\\geq 1 +3p^{1/3}+3p^{2/3}+p=(1+p^{1/3})^3=(1+\sqrt[3]{9})^3\approx 29.2204$$
where $p=abc=9$ and the minimum is attained for $a=b=c=\sqrt[3]{9}$.

Comment: Although i'm not OP, i have a question. What is wrong with the method posted in the question which leads to a smaller minimum? Is it because we bound each term in the product and thus our overall bound also decreases?

Comment: @Hikaru Yes. Note that if $a\not=1$ then $(1+a)/2>\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(1+a)\,(1+b)\,(1+c)=1+a+b+c+a\,b+a\,c+b\,c+a\,b\,c.$$ Now apply AM-GM to the sums $a+b+c$ and $a\,b+a\,c+b\,c$.

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM
\begin{align}
1+a &\geq 2 \sqrt{a} \\
1+b &\geq 2 \sqrt{b} \\
1+c &\geq 2 \sqrt{c} 
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) &\geq 2^3 \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}\sqrt{c} \\
&= 8.\sqrt{9} \ldots
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: the solution in the question says the same. but if (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)=24. For what value of a, b and c the product abc=9?

Comment: @RobertZ Exactly...